# Dependent / Cascading Dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, get

I am using the cascading dropdown jquery plugin. ( https://github.com/dnasir/jquery-cascading-dropdown)

I have two dropdowns. 'Client' and 'Site'.

Based on which client you select, the sites list should be appropriately reduced to only show the sites for the selected client. I have setup two php scripts returnClientList.php and returnSiteList.php that successfully return json arrays with a label/value pair.

My problem is that I cannot reduce the site list, after selecting the client. The event successfully fires but I only get the full list back. As you will see, the code is using the getJSON request which i know from the manual sends a HTTP GET. Looking at the *network* panel of chrome reveals that there is no GET value actually being sent.

Hopefully something obvious but I am new to jquery so help appreciated.

My code:

JS

```
$('#edit-shift').cascadingDropdown({
selectBoxes: [
    {
      selector: '.clients',
      source: function(request, response) {
      $.getJSON('returnClientList.php', request, function(data) {
                  var selectOnlyOption = data.length <= 1;
                  response($.map(data, function(item, index) {
                      return {
                          label: item.label,
                          value: item.value,
                          selected: selectOnlyOption // Select if only option
                      };
                  }));
              });
          }
    },
    {
        selector: '.sites',
        requires: ['.clients'],
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON('returnSiteList.php', request, function(data) {
                var selectOnlyOption = data.length <= 1;
                response($.map(data, function(item, index) {
                    return {
                        label: item.label,
                        value: item.value,
                        selected: selectOnlyOption // Select if only option
                    };
                }));
            });

        }
    },
    {
        onChange: function(event, value, requiredValues){}
    }
]
});
```

PHP

```
//this script returns a json array for use in jquery autocomplete fields for site     lists...
header('Content-type: application/json');
require("connect.php");

$client_id = $_GET['?'];

 //do the query for sites that are active
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM site WHERE active=1 AND client_id='$client_id' ORDER BY site_name ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

//loop the results and create php array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $arr[] = array('label' => $row['site_name'], 'value' => $row['id']);
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing my own solution to this and scrapped the plugin. Enjoy.

```
//dynamically returns the sites once the user chooses a client - edit/add shift form
  $('.client-id').change(function () {
    var selectedClient = $(this).val();
    if (selectedClient != null && selectedClient != '') {

        $.getJSON('returnSiteList.php', { id: selectedClient }, 
                    function (Sites) {
                      var siteSelect = $('.site-id');
                      siteSelect.empty();
                      $.each(Sites, function (index, site) {
                      siteSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                      value: site.value,
                      text: site.label
                }));
            });
        });
    }
});
```